# xcopy files created this month in PowerShell

Tags: command-line, powershell, xcopy

I wrote this code to copy files, what I need is a way to make it copy just the files created this month or created last 31 days?

```
$a = "L:\EndMonths\"
$a +=get-date -format MMMM
xcopy "L:\28*.zip" $a /I
xcopy "L:\29*.zip" $a /I
xcopy "L:\30*.zip" $a /I
xcopy "L:\31*.zip" $a /I
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get files from this month, use:

```
$date = Get-Date -Format M-1-y
```

or to get files from the last 31 days use:

```
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-31).ToString('M-d-y')
```

Then call xcopy like:

```
xcopy "L:\28*.zip" $a /I /D:$date
```